# Where can I find the detailed syntax for webapp2 session.get in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am looking for the syntax for ALL the variation of all the webapp2_extras functions and APIs.

For example, I could find nowhere that defined the various parameters of a webapp2_extras session.get on the webapp2 web site.

For example, I found through trial and error that I could define a default value on a session.get (e.g. cntr = self.session.get('cntr', 0) ) but I could find no place that indicated this might be a viable structure.

Can anyone tell me where I might find such detailed documentation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation can be found at [WebApp Improved](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/).

In your case you can use `self.session.get('cntr', 0)`, because session is a dictionary-like object, and as such its get method receives a default value as a parameter. See the [Session documentation](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html) for further details.

The docs for the webapp extras are [here](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/index.html#api-reference-webapp2-extras).

Answer (score 0):

I know Bill G. isn't a big fan of open source, but webapp2 is open source.  If something is missing from the docs, you can find it in the code.

https://github.com/moraes/webapp-improved/blob/master/webapp2_extras/sessions.py

You'll see that the session object is derived from a python dict, so that get() function you're using is the python dict get() function, which allows for default values.

I'm pretty impressed that you found that by trial and error though.

Comment: What makes you conclude that I am not a big fan of open source?  In fact, the opposite is the case. I love the community involvement in open source projects such as Drupal, Joomla, DotNetNuke (which in my view are more application frameworks than CMS) where literally thousands of modules have been developed and are being enhanced by teams of volunteers.

But where is the equivalent library of thousands of modules for GAE?  Am I missing something or is GAE either basically dead or are the people using it not open-source oriented or did I just not see where the library is.

Please advise.

Comment: It was a joke, I was referring to another http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/news/exec/billg/  I haven't done a comparison of how many open source packages are specifically for GAE as compared to say AWS, but there's plenty of open source packages written either in Java or Python that just work on GAE.  It is unfortunate that most packages written for SQL won't work.

Comment: I was referring to the apparent lack of modules for GAE that one could simply plug into ones own app (modules written for Python/datastore.  I get the impression that there is very little community sharing of modules such as ability to add comments, or newsletters, or Blogs, etc.

One is left with the impression that one must hand code every little things one's self.

I keep thinking this is not possible in today's world and that I have just not seen where the module repository for GAE is where there are already thousands of modules to chose from.  Do you know where there is such a repository?

Comment: I don't know of any single repository, but for example, if you're looking for a CMS, you can search for "google app engine CMS" on google, and a bunch of results pop up.  I'm currently running on djang-nonrel, and have 6 open source django (non-GAE specific) plugins working.  I'm also using an number of other open source python libraries (also, non-GAE specific).